# Mold coming from laminate - how to evaluate what's underneath?

Tags: mold, laminate-floor

**Appartment**

There is laminate in my 55m² appartment, except for kitchen and bathroom. Underneath that is some sort of "foam mat" *(don't know the exact term)*.

At the desk below my chair there is a PVC mat that I have screwed to the floor on all 4 corners so that the chair doesn't damage the laminate. However, the laminate was already just slightly damaged *(really slightly)*.

**Current Situation**

Below the mat, I have spotted **green and white mold dots**. So I opened the windows, lifted the mat and spoiled everything generously in alcohol.

After this, I have cleaned the mat with alcohol and the floor very generously over a few days to remove what's on the surface. Any cleaning utilities were long gone after an hour at max.

**The big question however is...**

How do I evaluate what it looks like underneath the laminate prior to possibly replacing it? What should I do in order to accomplish **complete decontamination?**

Comment: Can you post some pictures?  Can you better describe the location and what might be under the laminate?  What is the nature of the laminate?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't make a photo. The laminate is pressed wood spans and my concerns why it might be *under* it is because mold seemed to be more present between each laminate piece. Underneath it is some sort of "foam" planes, as far as I can remember when moving in 3 years ago.